# How do get label on left side of single element wiht ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a tab:

```
var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
                                xtype:'tabpanel',
                                activeTab: 0,
                                autoScroll: false,
                            //  layoutOnTabChange: true,
                                  defaults:{
                                    bodyPadding: 10,
                                    layout: 'anchor'
                                },
                                items: [{
                                    title:'Общие сведения',
                                    layout:'column',
                                    items:[{
                                        columnWidth:.5,
                                        layout: 'form',
                                        items: [{
                                            xtype:'textfield',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Площадь кв.м.',
                                            name: 'area',
                                            anchor:'80%'
                                        },{
                                            labelAlign: 'left',
                                            xtype:'checkbox',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Межевание',
                                            name: 'mezj',
                                            anchor:'80%'
                                        },{
                                            xtype:'textfield',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Кадастровая стоимость',
                                            name: 'paid',
                                            anchor:'80%'
                                        },{
                                            xtype:'textfield',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Тип переоформленного права',
                                            name: 'right',
                                            anchor:'80%'
                                        },{
                                            xtype:'textfield',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Код документа',
                                            name: 'doc_id',
                                            anchor:'80%'
                                        }]
                                    }
////**/////
```

And how its looks:

[image]

You see that all labels places on top. Its allright but i want to place checkbox's label on right.

```
xtype:'checkbox',
fieldLabel: 'Межевание',
name: 'mezj',
anchor:'80%',
labelAlign: 'left',
```

I use this but not help. IOts possible to change labelAlign of single element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the boxLabel property instead of the fieldLabel to get your label on the right side of the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks its works. But its possible to put label on left side?

Comment: You had it on the left side :) you probably did not have enough width to accommodate the label and the input.